# How to graph a functions without using calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

How to graph function: $$ y=\frac{6 \sqrt x}{\sqrt x+2}$$
 without using calculus?

I wanted to use transformations to graph but I did not know where to start.

Comment: Plugging in easy numbers then graphing manually? Finding asymptotes?

Comment: You could just make a table of $x,y$ pairs in a spreadsheet using fill and copy down, then graph the result.  You could feed it to Alpha or Desmos.  What tools are allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to do it truly by hand, probably the easiest is to write
$$y=6-\frac {12}{\sqrt x + 2}$$
which makes it clear there is a horizontal asymptote at $6$.  You need $x \ge 0$ for the square roots to make sense, so plug in numbers that are easy to take the square root of, like $0,1,4,9,16$ for $x$ and plot the points.  You might even do $x=\frac 14$ because that is easy to take the square root of.  You will get something like this from [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%206*sqrt%28x%29%2F%28sqrt%28x%29%2B2%29%20from%200%20to%2010)
[image]

Comment: +1 Nice answer! @Kasiopea: The transformation is motivated by the fact that for rational functions a standard initial step is to rewrite the rational function as (polynomial) + (proper fraction), where by "proper fraction" I mean the denominator's degree is greater than the numerator's degree. Then the "far away" view of the graph will be the polynomial, and issues about vertical asymptotes and such are dealt with by the proper fraction part. The function you're dealing with is not a rational function, but its form is sufficiently close to one that the same idea should suggest itself to you.